# keep all rows in group when a row contains a specified substring pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got data that looks like this:

```
    ID#     DATE        TEXT
    1       1/1/2017    ENTERED BY A
    1       1/1/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    1       1/2/2017    ENTERED BY B
    1       1/2/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    1       1/2/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    2       1/4/2017    SUPPLEMENTAL PAYMENT BY A
    2       1/4/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    3       1/1/2017    ENTERED BY C
    3       1/2/2017    CHANGED COMPANY NAME
    3       1/2/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

I'm trying to group the data by ID# and DATE and return all rows when a group (in this I'm grouping on case ID# and DATE) has a text match.

Here's what I've got so far. The code below is attempting to search each row in the TEXT field for the substring 'ENTERED BY' and return all rows associated with that group.

```
    notes[notes.groupby('ID#','DATE',as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['TEXT'].str.contains('ENTERED BY'))]
```

I've also tried variations of group.filter() with similar results. Anybody that can point me in the right direction? My output set should look like this:

```
    ID#     DATE        TEXT
    1       1/1/2017    ENTERED BY A
    1       1/1/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    1       1/2/2017    ENTERED BY B
    1       1/2/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    1       1/2/2017    BLAH BLAH BLAH
    3       1/1/2017    ENTERED BY C
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.any.html) and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df=df[df['TEXT'].str.contains('ENTERED BY').groupby([df['ID#'],df['DATE']]).transform('any')]
print (df)
   ID#      DATE            TEXT
0    1  1/1/2017    ENTERED BY A
1    1  1/1/2017  BLAH BLAH BLAH
2    1  1/2/2017    ENTERED BY B
3    1  1/2/2017  BLAH BLAH BLAH
4    1  1/2/2017  BLAH BLAH BLAH
7    3  1/1/2017    ENTERED BY C
```

Detail:

```
print (df['TEXT'].str.contains('ENTERED BY'))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: TEXT, dtype: bool

print(df['TEXT'].str.contains('ENTERED BY').groupby([df['ID#'],df['DATE']]).transform('any'))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
9    False
Name: TEXT, dtype: bool
```

Another faster solution is filter all `ID#` and `DATE` with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df=df.loc[df['TEXT'].str.contains('ENTERED BY'), ['ID#','DATE']].drop_duplicates().merge(df)
print (df)
   ID#      DATE            TEXT
0    1  1/1/2017    ENTERED BY A
1    1  1/1/2017  BLAH BLAH BLAH
2    1  1/2/2017    ENTERED BY B
3    1  1/2/2017  BLAH BLAH BLAH
4    1  1/2/2017  BLAH BLAH BLAH
5    3  1/1/2017    ENTERED BY C
```

Detail:

```
print (df.loc[df['TEXT'].str.contains('ENTERED BY'), ['ID#','DATE']].drop_duplicates())
   ID#      DATE
0    1  1/1/2017
2    1  1/2/2017
7    3  1/1/2017
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000

L = ['AV','DF','SD','RF','F','WW','FG','SX']
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-02-20')
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEXT': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'ID#':np.random.randint(3000, size=N),
                   'DATE': np.random.choice(dates, N)})
       .sort_values(['ID#','DATE']).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)
```

---

```
In [375]: %timeit df.loc[df['TEXT'].str.contains('A'), ['ID#','DATE']].drop_duplicates().merge(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 96.1 ms per loop

In [376]: %timeit df[df['TEXT'].str.contains('A').groupby([df['ID#'],df['DATE']]).transform('any')]
1 loop, best of 3: 6.56 s per loop

#Wen solution
In [377]: %timeit df.groupby(['ID#','DATE'],as_index=False).filter(lambda x : x.TEXT.str.contains('A').sum().any())
1 loop, best of 3: 30.1 s per loop
```